# Python list slicing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I just observed a behavior with python lists and wanted why and how it works.

If I have a list say `my_list = [5]`
Why does `my_list[1:]` give me `[]` as the output but `my_list[1]` give me an `IndexError`

Comment: my_list[1] is to access 1st element and my_list[1:] is to position 1 to the end.  Out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully in the list slicing. Please read slicing examples in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: `my_list[1]` is actually for the second element, not first. Lists are 0-based.

Comment: yes, I consider my_list[0] as to access zeroth element. :)